# UIImage imageWithData returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

On my app I have some C++ image recognition software, and I'm trying to save image recognized by this C++ functions.

I have this array to store image recognized:

```
int _detectedImages[NSMaxNumDetections ][NSPatchSize * NSPatchSize];
```

I call the C++ function this way:

```
numberOfDetections = nativeDetect(_resultImages);
```

And with the following code, I try to convert data from `_detectedImages` to `UIImage`.

```
for (int index = 0; index < numberOfDetections; index++)
{
    if (_resultImages[index] != nil)
    {
        NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&_resultImages[index] length:sizeof(_resultImages[index])];
        NSLog(@"##### Image data size: %d", [imageData length]);
        UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _lastDetectedSignImages[index] = newImage;
    }
}
```

On the log I get this:

```
#### Image data size: 2304
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM setObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

`newImage` is nil but `imageData` has data.

**Am I doing something wrong when I try to get an `UIImage` from that data?**

The other possibility if that my C++ recognition software is doing something wrong, but I'm not going to show you that code here (sorry, it's copyrighted).

Or I'm not passing `_resultImages` correctly to `nativeDetect`.

Comment: I've tried reproducing this using a UIImage converted to NSData using UIImagePNGRepresentation(), but I'm not seeing an issue with the same code you have in your for() loop - are you sure the data coming out of nativeDetect() is usable? Should be easy to prove or disprove by trying to restore an individual image in a unit test ...

Comment: I think so. How can I see if that data is usable? I have thought to print out to `NSLog`.

Comment: Having given it some thought, you've already shown it isn't usable based on what comes out of the byte array :). If you have access to the implementation of the function, you could test what's put in there, but if you don't I'd get in contact with the authors.

Comment: I think I don't pass `_resultImages` by reference to `nativeDetect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost for sure your C++ images are in some bitmap format - RGBA etc. So your first task is to figure out what that format is (and the byte order too!). With that information you can use CGImageCreate() to create a CGImageRef. With that you can create a UIImage.

Comment: If you really struggle with that, you can save one image to a file, upload the file and all the relevant information you have on the C++ library's image format (which they MUST provide), and add a bounty to this question to anyone who gives you the code back that properly decodes it on an ios device (say 100pts).